# How do I grab specific posts (by post id) and display the title, featured image, and excerpt?

Tags: hooks, content

I'm trying to help a friend get his site in order and he wants me to swap out the "services" posts on the front page with 4 specific posts. Thing is, I don't know the right way to do this dynamically. How do I call up the content of just the post id, the featured-image (with the right dimensions) and a short excerpt from the beginning of the post?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated; thanks.

Comment: You will need to add more detail. These posts, are they posts or custom post types, are services a category or a custom taxonomy....,

Comment: They are a custom post type, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this but based on your question, this should get you on track:

```
<?php

$id = 4; // The Page or post ID
$page_data = get_post( $id );
$title = $page_data->post_title;
$content = $page_data->post_content;
$excerpt = substr($content, 0, 155);
$featured_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($id, 'thumbnail') );

?>

<div class="post">
<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
<div class="featured"><img src="<?php echo $featured_image; ?>" /></div>
<p class="excerpt"><strong><?php echo $excerpt; ?></strong></p>
<p class="content"><?php echo $content; ?></p>
</div>
```